# When replace xml contents containing special characters during parsing

Tags: python, xml

I am parsing a 3gb xml file that has a complex structure with xml.sax in python.
When the 3gb xml file contains special characters like '<', it results in errors.

I wonder how I can replace the special characters with '<' simultaneously to operate a parser successfully.

I was trying to catch its contents through the regex, but it is not easy for me.

```
<DC.Title><main>Characteristics of the interaction mechanism between tannic <acid> and sodium caseinate using multispectroscopic and thermodynamics methods</main>
</DC.Title>
```

From this, I want to extract the following.

```
Characteristics of the interaction mechanism between tannic <acid> and sodium caseinate using multispectroscopic and thermodynamics methods
```

but it leads to an error because of '<', a special character in xml.

I tried to use methods in the ContentHandler class.

Using regular expressions, replacing special characters is hard, and xml.sax in python is not able to handle this problem.

I guess I should exchange every special character like '<'. Is my assumption right? If so, how can I do this? Is there any other way to parse my xml file?

=============================================
added below(actual xml)

```
<NDSL_Articles>
<Article><DC.Identifier><controlNumber>73113660</controlNumber>
<controlNumber.source.BL>RN602387147</controlNumber.source.BL><controlNumber.source>JAKO201857968658354</controlNumber.source>
<journal scheme="URL">http://society.kisti.re.kr/journal/kj_view.jsp?kj=HJTODO&amp;soc=etri&amp;ndsl=y</journal>
<article scheme="URL">http://society.kisti.re.kr/journal/view.jsp?soc=etri&amp;kj=HJTODO&amp;py=2018&amp;vol=40&amp;iss=2&amp;sp=283&amp;ndsl=y</article>
<article.source scheme="KOI">KISTI1.1003/JNL.JAKO201857968658354</article.source>
<article.source scheme="URL">http://koix.kisti.re.kr/KISTI1.1003/JNL.JAKO201857968658354</article.source>
<article scheme="DOI">http://dx.doi.org/10.4218/etrij.15.0114.0065</article>
<article.source scheme="ACMS_CN2">etri/HJTODO_2018_v40n2_283</article.source>
<paper scheme="ISSN">1225-6463</paper>
<publicationID.source>HJTODO</publicationID.source>
</DC.Identifier>
<DC.Relation><isPartOf>
<title>ETRI Journal</title>
<volume>v.40 no.2</volume>
<sourcePage>283-283</sourcePage>
<startPage>283</startPage>
<lastPage>283</lastPage>
<type>Journal</type>
</isPartOf></DC.Relation>
<DC.Description><reference.count>0</reference.count></DC.Description>
<DC.Format><Pages>1</Pages></DC.Format>
<DC.Language><text scheme="USMARC">eng</text></DC.Language>
<DC.Creator><personal><main>Hong, Kang Woon</main><affiliation>Department of Information and Communications Engineering, KAIST, Broadcasting &amp; Telecommunications Media Research Laboratory, ETRI</affiliation><email>kangwoon@kaist.ac.kr, gwhong@etri.re.kr</email></personal><personal><main>Ryu, Won</main><affiliation>Broadcasting &amp; Telecommunications Media Research Laboratory, ETRI</affiliation></personal></DC.Creator>
<DC.Title><main>Corrigendum</main>
</DC.Title>
<DC.Publisher><main>Electronics and Telecommunications Research Institute</main><alternative>한국전자통신연구원</alternative></DC.Publisher>
<DC.Date><created scheme="ISO 8601">2018-04-01</created></DC.Date>
<DC.Type>Article</DC.Type>
<NDSL.Usage scheme="freetext">eletronic</NDSL.Usage>
<NDSL.Cataloging>  <instituion scheme="Internal">BL</instituion>  <source.version>KISTI XML기반의 학술정보 및 협회기술정보 가공 지침서 v.1.0</source.version>  <date scheme="ISO 8601">2015-09-25T13:48:09</date>  <name>BL</name>  <instituion.lastUpdate scheme="Internal">NDSL 센터</instituion.lastUpdate>  <date.lastUpdate scheme="ISO 8601">2018-07-12T11:17:45</date.lastUpdate>  <name.lastUpdate>김순영</name.lastUpdate>  </NDSL.Cataloging>
</Article>

<DC.DOI>
<doi>http://dx.doi.org/10.4218/etrij.15.0114.0065</doi>
</DC.DOI>
</NDSL_Articles>
```

Comment: Please post your relevant actual code & identify the specific error being reported.

Comment: The problem is that there is no `</acid>` end tag, which makes the input ill-formed.

Comment: I mean '<' and '>' are not tag just special character!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the little information you provided, assuming all your data has a similar format. I would use `BeautifulSoup` to extract the data.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
a = BeautifulSoup("<DC.Title><main>Characteristics of the interaction mechanism between tannic <acid> and sodium caseinate using multispectroscopic and thermodynamics methods</main></DC.Title>", "html.parser")
print(a.main)
```

For example the above code prints out contents of `<main>`:

`<main>Characteristics of the interaction mechanism between tannic <acid> and sodium caseinate using multispectroscopic and thermodynamics methods</acid></main>`

Tags like `<acid>` will prevent us using `a.text`, and i don't have enough info to help you with that, so you'll have to deal with that yourself.

Comment: My file is 3gb file, which means it occurs memory error when I was using beautifulsoup. That's why I am trying to use sax.

Comment: Maybe separate into different files? I suggest you post at least 3 paragraphs of the file so we at least know what to work with

Comment: I added some of xml.